# D3 cluster layout child in circular format

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I am trying to design a circular cluster layout ,here when i click the node containing child i appears like [image: this]

but i want to get the child in circular format like [image: this]
how can i do this...any suggestions will be helpful.....
here is the fiddle -  https://jsfiddle.net/etkm3qvo/

here is my code:

```js
var data = {
  "name": "அகல்",
  "children": [{
    "name": "விலகு",
    "color": "red"
  }, {
    "name": "நீங்கு",
    "color": "red",
    "t": "நீங்குதல், பாயிருளகல (புறநா.25).",
    "children": [{
      "name": "விலகு",
      "color": "red"
    }, {
      "name": "பின்னிடு",
      "color": "red"
    }, {
      "name": "ஒதுங்கு",
      "color": "red"
    }, {
      "name": "இடம்விட்டுப் பெயர்",
      "color": "red"
    }, {
      "name": "பிரி",
      "color": "red"
    }, {
      "name": "பின்வாங்கு",
      "color": "red"
    }]
  }, {
    "name": "பிரி",
    "color": "red",
    "t": "பிரிதல். அகன்ற பூங்கொடியை (பாரத.குரு.79)"
  }, {
    "name": "கட",
    "color": "#1E90FF",
    "t": "கடத்தல். (திவா.)"
  }, {
    "name": "விருத்தியடை",
    "color": "green",
    "t": "விருத்தியடைதல் (குறள்,170.)"
  }, {
    "name": "விசாலி",
    "color": "#00C957",
    "t": "விசாலித்தல். (புறநா.3,16.)"
  }, {
    "name": "நீட்டு",
    "color": "#00C957"
  }, {
    "name": "விரி",
    "color": "#00C957"
  }, {
    "name": "பரப்பு",
    "color": "#00C957"
  }, {
    "name": "விரிவு",
    "color": "#00C957"
  }, {
    "name": "விளக்குத் தகழி",
    "color": "#D15FEE",
    "t": "விளக்குத் தகழி. திருவிளக்குத் திரியிட்டங் ககல்பரப்பி(பெரியபு.கலிய .15). "
  }, {
    "name": "சட்டி",
    "color": "orange",
    "t": "சட்டி. காரகற்கூவியன் (பெரும்பாண். 377)",
    "children": [{
      "name": "மட்பாண்டம்",
      "color": "red"
    }, {
      "name": "உலோகத்தட்டு",
      "color": "red"
    }, {
      "name": "திதி",
      "color": "green"
    }, {
      "name": "அறுபது",
      "color": "orange"
    }, {
      "name": "தாமரை",
      "color": "purple"
    }, {
      "name": "அழித்தல்",
      "color": "brown"
    }, {
      "name": "கொல்லுதல்",
      "color": "brown"
    }]
  }, {
    "name": "ஓர் அளவு",
    "color": "blue",
    "t": "ஓர் அளவு. (தொல்.எழுத்.170,உரை.)"
  }, {
    "name": "வெள்வேல்",
    "color": "maroon",
    "t": "(சங்.அக.)"
  }, {
    "name": "உள்ளூர்",
    "color": "purple",
    "t": "(பொதி. நி.) "
  }, {
    "name": "ஊரின் உட்புறம்",
    "color": "purple",
    "t": "ஊரின் உட்புறம். (பொதி. நி.)"
  }, {
    "name": "நாடு",
    "color": "brown",
    "t": "நாடு. (பொதி. நி.)",
    "children": [{
      "name": "தேடு",
      "color": "red"
    }, {
      "name": "ஆராய்",
      "color": "red"
    }, {
      "name": "தெரி",
      "color": "red"
    }, {
      "name": "அள",
      "color": "red"
    }, {
      "name": "கிட்டு",
      "color": "red"
    }, {
      "name": "விரும்பு",
      "color": "green"
    }, {
      "name": "நினை",
      "color": "green"
    }, {
      "name": "மோப்பம்பிடி",
      "color": "green"
    }, {
      "name": "தேசம்",
      "color": "purple"
    }, {
      "name": "இடம்",
      "color": "purple"
    }, {
      "name": "பூமி",
      "color": "purple"
    }, {
      "name": "இராச்சியம்",
      "color": "purple"
    }, {
      "name": "நாட்டுப்புறம்",
      "color": "purple"
    }, {
      "name": "உலகம்",
      "color": "purple"
    }, {
      "name": "மருதநிலம்",
      "color": "purple"
    }, {
      "name": "பக்கம்",
      "color": "orange"
    }, {
      "name": "8 பதுமம்",
      "color": "blue"
    }]
  }, {
    "name": "8 பதுமம்",
    "color": "maroon"
  }]
};

var i = 0;
var duration = 700;
var root;
var width = 1000;
var height = 1000;
var radius = 550 / 2;

var cluster = d3.layout.cluster()
  .size([360, radius - 120])
  .separation(function(a, b) {
    return (a.children == b.children ? 1 : 2) / a.depth;
  });
var diagonal = d3.svg.diagonal.radial()
  .projection(function(d) {
    return [d.y, d.x / 180 * Math.PI];
  });

var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
  .attr("width", width)
  .attr("height", height)
  .append("g")
  .attr("transform", "translate(" + 500 + "," + 0 + ")");
root = data;
root.x0 = height / 2;
root.y0 = 0;
var baseSvg = d3.select("#tree-container").append("svg")
  .attr("width", width)
  .attr("height", height)
  .attr("class", "overlay");

function collapse(d) {

  if (d.children) {
    d._children = d.children;
    d._children.forEach(collapse);
    d.children = null;
  }

  update(d);
}

function toggleChildren(d) {
  if (d.children) {

    d._children = d.children;
    d.children = null;
  } else if (d._children) {
    d.children = d._children;
    d._children = null;
  }
  return d;
}

function click(d) {
  if (!d.parent) {
    return;
  }
  if (!d.children)
    data.children.forEach(collapse);

  if (d3.event.defaultPrevented) return;

  d = toggleChildren(d);

  update(d);
}

function update(source) {


  var nodes = cluster.nodes(root);
  links = cluster.links(nodes);
  nodes.forEach(function(d) {
    d.y = d.depth * 130;
  });
  var node = svgGroup.selectAll("g.node")
    .data(nodes, function(d) {
      return d.id ||
        (d.id = ++i);
    });


  var nodeEnter = node.enter().append("g")
    .attr("class", "node")

    .attr("transform", function(d) {
      return "translate(" + project(d.x, d.y) + ")";
    })
    .on("click", click);

  function project(x, y) {
    var angle = (x - 90) / 180 * Math.PI,
      radius = y;
    return [radius * Math.cos(angle), radius * Math.sin(angle)];

  }
  nodeEnter.append("circle")
    .attr("class", "smallcircle")
    .style("stroke", function(d) {
      return d.color;
    })
    .on("mouseover", function(d) {
      var r = d3.select(this).node().getBoundingClientRect();
      d3.select("div#tooltip")
        .style("display", "inline")
        .style("top", (r.top - 25) + "px")
        .style("top", 10 + "px")
        .style("left", (d3.event.pageX) + "px")
        .style("top", (d3.event.pageY - 40) + "px")
        .style("left", r.left + 80 + "px")
        .style("left", +"px")
        .style("position", "absolute")
        .text(d.tooltip);
    })
    .on("mouseout", function() {
      d3.select("div#tooltip").style("display", "none")
    })

  nodeEnter.append("text")
    .text(function(d) {
      return d.name;
    })
    .style("opacity", 1)
    .style("fill-opacity", 0);

  node.select("circle.nodeCircle")
    .attr("r", 4.5)
  var nodeUpdate = node.transition()
    .duration(duration)
    .attr("transform", function(d) {
      return "rotate(" + (d.x - 90) + ") translate(" + d.y + ") rotate(" + (-d.x + 90) + ")";
    });

  nodeUpdate.select("circle")
    .attr("r", 4.5)

    .style("fill", function(d) {
      if (d._children) {
        return d.color;
      }
    });
  window.onload = nn();

  function nn() {
    d3.select('text').style("stroke", "red");
    d3.select('text').style("font-size", "20px");
    d3.select('text').attr("x", function(d) {
      return d.x < 180 === d.children ? 5 : -1;
    })
    d3.select('text').attr("y",
      function(d) {
        return d.y < 180 === d.children ? 20 : -20;
      })
  }
  nodeUpdate.select("text")
    .style("fill", d => d.color)
    .style("fill-opacity", 9)
    .attr("font-size", "14px")
    .attr("font-weight", function(d) {
      return d.children ? "bolder" : "lighter";
    })
    .attr("dy", ".35em")
    .attr("x", function(d) {
      return d.x < 180 ===
        !d.children ? 6 : -6;
    })
    .style("text-anchor", function(d) {
      return d.x < 180 === !d.children ? "start" : "end";
    })
    .attr("transform", function(d) {
      return d.children ? "rotate(360)" : "rotate(" + (d.x < 180 ? d.x - 90 : d.x + 90) + ")";
    });
  var nodeExit = node.exit().transition()
    .duration(duration)
    .remove();

  nodeExit.select("circle")
    .attr("r", 1e-6);

  nodeExit.select("text")
    .style("fill-opacity", 1e-6);


  var link = svgGroup.selectAll("path.link")
    .data(links, function(d) {
      return d.target.id;
    });


  link.enter().insert("path", "g")
    .attr("class", "link")
    .style("stroke", function(d) {
      return d.target.color;
    })
    .attr("d", function(d) {
      var o = {
        x: source.x,
        y: source.y
      };
      return diagonal({
        source: o,
        target: o
      });
    });


  link.transition()
    .duration(duration)
    .attr("d", diagonal);


  link.exit().transition()
    .duration(duration)
    .attr("d", function(d) {
      var o = {
        x: source.x,
        y: source.y
      };
      return diagonal({
        source: o,
        target: o
      });
    })
    .remove();


  nodes.forEach(function(d) {
    d.x0 = d.x;
    d.y0 = d.y;
  });
}
var svgGroup = baseSvg.append("g")
  .attr("transform", "translate(" + 550 + "," + 300 + ")")
root.children.forEach(function(child) {
  collapse(child);
});
update(root);
d3.select(self.frameElement).style("height", 10);
```

```css
.node circle {
  fill: #fff;
  stroke: black;
  stroke-width: 1.5px;
}

.node {
  font: 10px sans-serif;
}

.link {
  fill: none;
  stroke: #ccc;
  stroke-width: 1px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.5.17/d3.js"></script>

<div id="viz" class="dd"></div>
<div id="tree-container" class="full"></div>
```